# WebMatrix SQL CE numeric type has zero precision

Tags: sql-server-ce, webmatrix, numeric, currency, sql-server-ce-4

I created a column in SQL CE database with "numeric" type, precision 10 and scale 5 using WebMatrix.
Then, I saved the table, and precision/scale suddenly changed to 0.

When I try to edit them, I receive the following error:

```
Error
---------------------------
The maximum precision for this type is 0.
---------------------------
OK
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is it a bug in either WebMatrix or SQL CE?

**Update: The bug seems to be fixed with latest WebMatrix version**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in the database management tools provided by WebMatrix: [http://forums.asp.net/t/1690824.aspx/1?WebMatrix+numeric+type+has+0+precision](http://forums.asp.net/t/1690824.aspx/1?WebMatrix%20numeric%20type%20has%200%20precision)